# $Q=Q_1+Q_2,Y=a\times {Q_1}^m+b\times {Q_2}^n$: how to take derivative w.r.t. the sum of two variables

Tags: derivatives

**How to take the derivative with respect to the sum of two variables?**

> $Q=Q_1+Q_2$
> $Y=a\times {Q_1}^m+b\times {Q_2}^n$

Can we take the derivative of $Y$ with respect to $Q$? Can this be solved using this method?

Comment: I hardly see how, since $Y$ is not a function of $Q$.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much!

Comment: Y is a function of Q because Q_1 is a function of Q